# Store numbers in an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have started learning MATLAB and I was given a program to take ten number as input from the user of the program.
According to my knowledge of C, i simply wrote

```
for i=1:1:10
      fscanf('%d',num(i));
end
```

But an error occurred saying that Error using fscanf.
So my question is to ask about how to take ten numbers from the user and directly store them in an array, simliar to what we usually do in C.
Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Of course you can't just copy your C code and expect it to work with MATLAB. Also this should be covered in every basic tutorial.

Comment: 5 seconds of google will give [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) result.

Comment: 5 seconds of Google, or just type `help fscanf` at the MATLAB command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
num = []; % ToInitializeTheArray

for i=1:5
     num =  input('Enter value or enter 100 to stop: ');
     num(end+1)=num;
end
```

I'm new to MathLab myself I hope this helped

Comment: Unless absolutely necessary not to, you should preallocate arrays to their max size rather than having them grow in a loop. Although your code won't actually grow beyond 2 identical elements because you overwrite `num` every iteration.